# Manipulate EIP in Immunity Debugger

Tags: windbg, immunity-debugger

I just was playing around with Windbg, debugging some application. 
At some point I had to manipulate EIP which was pretty easy in Windbg. But then once I switched back to Immunity, I could not figure out how to do the same thing.

Is there some way you can change the EIP inside Immunity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click the code, select 'New Origin here' done

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can select an address and press `ctrl + *` (use the `*` at the right pad)